# Кэшировать на сервере вывод из БД по запросу

Tags: php, база-данных, sqlite, запрос, кэширование

Ситуация такая: есть под сотню страниц, на которых публикуется вывод из БД (sqlite) по конкретным запросам. Сервер Apache, если это важно.

Мне нужно **при каждом первом за период запросе кэшировать результаты запроса к БД**, чтобы все последующие пользователи на этот запрос получали данные не из БД, а из кэша сервера.

На просторах сети вычитала некие рекомендации, но не работают они у меня.
**Не сохраняется ничего в папку cache**. Никаких файлов в ней не появляется.

Поправьте, что неправильно сделала. 
Спасибо!

Пишу так:

```
    <?php
if (file_exists('cache/2komnkv-exp.cache'))
    {  
        readfile('cache/2komnkv-exp.cache'); 
        exit();
    } 
ob_start();

    require_once './src/functions.php';
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
// тут весь конечный html, отдаваемый браузеру пользователя
</html>

<?php  
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush(); 
$fp = fopen('cache/2komnkv-exp.cache', 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, $buffer); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Сама папка cache создана мной лежит по тому же пути, что и html-файл, вызов которого должен должен кэшироваться.
Но есть еще какая-то папка .cache, находится на один уровень выше, в том же каталоге, что и папка www.

Comment: А файлы то появляются ? Если нет - то варианта 2: не правильный путь или недостаточно прав на запись в папку под пользователем, под которым выполняется php (это задает apache)

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Файлы не появляются.  Я как раз ищу информацию, как добавить скрипту права на запись в папку. Пока не нашла ничего. Путь указан относительно текущего файла, это может быть неправильно?

Comment: Сделайте `echo getcwd()` оно покажет текущий путь скрипта, относительно которого надо все указывать. С другой стороны require_once же работает, а оно точно написано относительно того же каталога. Права задаются в зависимости от особенностей хостинга. если есть командная строка то `chmod a+w cache`.

Comment: echo getcwd() показала папку, где лежат все html-ки. Именно там лежит и папка cache, и файл, который я пытаюсь кэшировать. Значит, в правах проблема?

Comment: да. других объяснений не вижу (ну разве что в php какая то ошибка, которую не видно и он до записи не доходит)

Comment: Спасибо, Mike. Что-то было у хостера с правами для php на создание файлов, видимо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, все пути указала вот так:

> (**DIR**.'/cache/2komnkv-exp.cache')

*Нижнее подчеркивание перед и после DIR не пропускает форма stackoverflow Константа указана, как и полагается.*

Но дело было не только в этом. **Какой-то трабл имелся с правами php на запись в указанную папку**, я думаю. Ибо долго хостер мне внушал всякое разное. Уже и пути были указаны именно так, но не работало сохранение кэша.

Я им про права php, они мне про пути.

В конце концов, со слов техподдержки, пересоздали папку cache, и все заработало.